Not smooth scrolling ont iOS/Android after creating controls on vertiscollbox at runtime by using Delphi 11.2
I wrote a very simple project by using delphi 11.2,
Drop a vertiscollbox on the form , and created 100 layouts on the vertiscollbox at runtime by clicking a button, inside every layout there are 2 labels and one rectangle for image…,
The program can run under windows, iOS and android, the only issue is when I scroll the whole list up and down by using finger on both iOS or android devices, I could feel the moving is not smooth. It causes some eye discomfort(looks like the content is shaking a bit).
I don’t want to use listview here, the listview is smooth(I have tested it).
Does anyone have suggestion?
Here is the code:
unit frMain;  
interface  
uses  
  System.SysUtils, System.Types, System.UITypes, System.Classes, System.Variants,
  FMX.Types,  System.IOUtils,FMX.Controls, FMX.Forms, FMX.Graphics, FMX.Dialogs, FMX.Layouts,
  FMX.Controls.Presentation, FMX.StdCtrls, FMX.Objects;  
type  
  TForm1 = class(TForm)  
    sb1: TVertScrollBox;  
    layout1: TLayout;  
    Label1: TLabel;  
    Label2: TLabel;  
    lb_title: TLabel;  
    lb_name: TLabel;  
    CornerButton1: TCornerButton;  
    img: TRectangle;  
    procedure FormShow(Sender: TObject);  
    procedure CornerButton1Click(Sender: TObject);  
  private  
    Y1 : Single;  
    procedure addItem(name, title, AFileName : String);    
  public  
    { Public declarations }  
  end;  
var  
  Form1: TForm1;  

implementation  
{$R *.fmx}  

procedure TForm1.addItem(name, title, AFileName: String);  
var  
  lo : TLayout;  
  var sPath:string;  
begin  
sPath:='1.jpg';  

{$IFDEF ANDROID}  
 sPath := System.IOUtils.TPath.Combine(System.IOUtils.TPath.GetDocumentsPath, '1.jpg');  
{$ENDIF}

{$IFDEF IOS}
 sPath := System.IOUtils.TPath.Combine(System.IOUtils.TPath.GetDocumentsPath, '1.jpg');
{$ENDIF}  

  lb_name.Text := name;  
  lb_title.Text := title;  
  img.Fill.Bitmap.Bitmap.LoadFromFile(sPath);  
  lo := TLayout(layout1.Clone(sb1));  
  lo.Width := sb1.Width - 32;  
  lo.Position.X := 16;  
  lo.Position.Y := Y1;  
  Y1 := Y1 + lo.Height + 12;  
  lo.Visible := True;  
  sb1.AddObject(lo);  
end;  

procedure TForm1.CornerButton1Click(Sender: TObject);  
var  
  i: Integer;  
begin  
  sb1.Content.DeleteChildren;  
  Y1 := 12;  
  for i := 0 to 100 do begin  
      addItem('Name ' + i.ToString, 'Title',  '1.jpg');  
  end;  
end;  

procedure TForm1.FormShow(Sender: TObject);  
begin  
  layout1.Visible := False;  
end;  
end.  



Hi, if you want very smooth scrolling you must use the Alcinoe delphi framework (https://github.com/MagicFoundation/Alcinoe/). their is a demo available on google play that show the smooth scrolling : https://play.google.com/apps/internaltest/4701218363717235793 but you must ask an access to it by writing a coment in https://github.com/MagicFoundation/Alcinoe/issues/331
